# Subtracting two column arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

I have this code where I want to subtract two 2x1 matrices in Python, but I am getting a wrong output.

I want my answer to be

```
[[-1.0]
 [1.0]
 [-1.0]]
```

but I am getting

```
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]].
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
test = np.zeros((3,1))
test[0] = 1.0
test[1] = 2.0
test[2] = 3.0


test1 = test
test1[0] = 2.0
test1[1] = 1.0
test1[2] = 4.0

ans = test - test1
print(ans)
```

Comment: both variables are referencing the same object, you’ll have to do test1 = test[:]

Answer (score 0):

You are simply initializing `test1` incorrectly.

See below change of `test1 = np.zeroes((3,1))`

```
import numpy as np

test = np.zeros((3,1))
test[0] = 1.0
test[1] = 2.0
test[2] = 3.0


test1 = np.zeros((3,1))
test1[0] = 2.0
test1[1] = 1.0
test1[2] = 4.0

ans = test - test1
print(ans)
```

Yields:

```
[[-1.]
 [ 1.]
 [-1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your `test1` variable is actually referencing `test`.

So basically you are subtracting a vector with itself, which obviously lead to a null vector.

You can verify this yourself:

```py
test1 = test
print(test1 is test)  # prints True
```

To avoid this behavior, you need to create a different object, for example using `copy` or slicing.

```py
test1 = test.copy()
print(test1 is test)  # prints False

test1 = test1[:]
print(test1 is test)  # prints False
```

This way you can initialize the new variable and get the expected results after vector subtraction.

```py
test1[0] = 2.0
test1[1] = 1.0
test1[2] = 4.0

ans = test - test1
print(ans)

# prints [[-1.]
#         [ 1.]
#         [-1.]]
```